# Invalid ELF header out of the gate running simple nodejs script

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a simple nodejs script on Ubuntu 14.04, the contents of which are as follows:

```
http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello World \n');
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

I've installed NodeJs via the instructions [found here](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/%5C). Here is the excerpt I followed from that link:

> **Option 2: Install Node.js with Ubuntu Package Manager**
>
> To install Node.js, type the following command in your terminal:
>
> `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
>
> Then install the Node package manager, npm:
>
> `sudo apt-get install npm`
>
> Create a symbolic link for node, as many Node.js tools use this name to execute.
>
> `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

I did that, verified that both packages are installed:

[image]

But I can't use my .node file without it complaining with this error:

```
user@host:/var/www/html/nodetest$ node test.node

module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: /var/www/html/nodetest/test.node: invalid ELF header
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

I've uninstalled and re-installed node as well as npm but it still doesn't work... I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit.

**Further information:**

I decided to build from source and after cloning `master` from https://github.com/nodejs/node.git and building it then running the same script, this is the error I get:

```
user@host:/var/www/html/nodetest$ ~/node/node test.node
module.js:600
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: /var/www/html/nodetest/test.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:600:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:414:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:529:3
```

It's the same error, obviously, with a different stack trace.

What gives?

Comment: Console output quoting would look much better than images, simply because of too much contrast introduced (and you're not running it under VM w/o copy-paste available as I can see).

Comment: Just a wild guess - couldn't it be about wrong file encoding of your script node.js fails to interpret? Like UTF8+BOM or UTF16...

Comment: I just tried the same steps on my Pi running Raspbian Jessie and the exact same thing happened. I haven't checked the encoding of the file yet but what encoding does nodejs need?

Comment: `file -i` returns `us-ascii`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welp, this is embarrassing(and actually, slightly infuriating).

> Invalid ELF header

is just a fancy way of NodeJS telling me that the file's extension was incorrect.

I ran

`mv test.node test.js`

to rename the file and now it works. That was a pretty annoying waste of two days because of a bad error message.

**Further explanation from robertklep in comments:**

> The file extension.node has special meaning for Node, as it's supposed
>   to be used for native (compiled) addons.
>   The "ELF header" part refers to how the dynamic loader
>   (`process.dlopen()` in the stack trace of the error) identifies that a
>   file is a compiled addon.Since you were feeding it a JS file, the
>   identification failed, so "invalid ELF header". That doesn't say
>   anything about the JS file, which was working just fine after you
>   renamed it.

Comment: The file extension `.node` has special meaning for Node, as it's supposed to be used for native (compiled) addons.

Comment: @robertklep That's wonderful. That makes sense now. So if I'm understanding correctly, it was telling me that if I'd wanted to run a `.node`, my ELF header was not correct. Not that the file itself was improperly formatted

Comment: The "ELF header" part refers to how the dynamic loader (`process.dlopen()` in the stack trace of the error) identifies that a file is a compiled addon. Since you were feeding it a JS file, the identification failed, so _"invalid ELF header"_. That doesn't say anything about the JS file, which was working just fine after you renamed it :D

Comment: That's actually hilarious. You obviously know a lot more than I do about this. If you want to add an answer to that effect, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Nah I'll just upvote your answer because it's correct (+ great that you were able to solve the problem, although I understand the frustration that it may have caused!)

Comment: Sounds good to me. I'll summarize in the answer then to hopefully help someone else. Thanks a bunch